# Executing bunch of hive queries (Building a DAG)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, workflow

**Background**

I am looking to execute a bunch of hive queries (around about 20-30 queries, and growing in number). Some of these queries depend on the result of few others, whereas some of them can be executed in parallel. (DAG)

**Question**

Is there a workflow manager which can take care of building a DAG (given the bunch of queries as input) and executing these queries parallely/sequentially (in the most optimium manner).

What are the best practices for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any tool for workflow management.Best practice depends on use case and expertise wise.

Traditionally in corporate :- Control-M or cron scheduler can be used.

From Big data ecosystem: oozie or azkaban

There are several other tools out there which can be used for workflow management.

Comment: Thanks Ashish.. I guess oozie and azkaban allow the user to build a DAG, but user intervention is required for DAG building. (That is my understanding of them.). Is there any such system which takes a series of queries as input, interprets the queries and builds a DAG by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Also this can be easily implemented in shell script
You can start parallel processes, wait for them, then start other processes.
Ampersand at the end of command instructs shell to run background process. See this example:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_DIR=/tmp/my_log_dir

#Set fail counter before parallel processes 
FAIL=0
echo "Parallel loading 1, 2 and 3..."

hive -hiveconf "some_var"="$some_value" -f myscript_1.hql 2>&1 | tee $LOG_DIR/myscript_1.log &
hive -hiveconf "some_var"="$some_value" -f myscript_2.hql 2>&1 | tee $LOG_DIR/myscript_2.log &
hive -hiveconf "some_var"="$some_value" -f myscript_3.hql 2>&1 | tee $LOG_DIR/myscript_3.log &

#Wait for three processes to finish
for job in `jobs -p`
do
echo $job
wait $job || let "FAIL+=1"
done

#Exit if some process has failed
if [ "$FAIL" != "0" ];
then
echo "Failed processes=($FAIL) Giving up..."
exit 1
fi

#Set fail counter before parallel processes 
FAIL=0
echo "Continue with next parallel steps 4,5..."
hive -hiveconf "some_var"="$some_value" -f myscript_4.hql 2>&1 | tee $LOG_DIR/myscript_4.log &
#and so on
```

Also there are other ways to run background processes:
https://www.codeword.xyz/2015/09/02/three-ways-to-script-processes-in-parallel/

Comment: Thanks. But i am interested more in outsourcing the DAG build up. Here you are specifically triggering myscript_1, myscript_2, myscript_3 in the first shot. Post that you trigger steps 4 and 5. Is there a standard tool which frees up the user from building up the DAG. (i.e. what the DAG looks like, how the DAG is build, i want to be completely abstracted from it). Is it too much of an ask.. assuming this would be a very common requirement.

Comment: Use wrapper script for generating DAGs from your representation for more abstraction. I'm currently working on similar task.  Need to generate DAGs from database containing queries/scripts and level+order. I'm going to generate DAG shell scripts then run them.

Comment: The Idea is that You already have some representation of DAGs. You just need to translate this representation to runnable script